# Chart paint event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, charts

Here's the code I'm running:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ChartTeste
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Graphics g;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            chart1.ChartAreas["Triangulos"].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
            chart1.ChartAreas["Triangulos"].AxisY.Maximum = 40;
            chart1.ChartAreas["Triangulos"].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
            chart1.ChartAreas["Triangulos"].AxisX.Maximum = 5;
            g = chart1.CreateGraphics();
        }

        private void chart1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Paint();
        }

        private void Paint()
        {
            Pen p = new Pen(Brushes.Red);
                chart1.Series["PreçoT"].Points.AddXY(1, 0);

                double posiX = chart1.ChartAreas["Triangulos"].AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(1);
                double posiY = chart1.ChartAreas["Triangulos"].AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(13);
                double posiY2 = chart1.ChartAreas["Triangulos"].AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(16);
                double max = chart1.ChartAreas["Triangulos"].AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(19);
                double min = chart1.ChartAreas["Triangulos"].AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(10);


                Point[] points = { new Point(Convert.ToInt32(posiX - 20), Convert.ToInt32(posiY)), new Point(Convert.ToInt32(posiX + 20), Convert.ToInt32(posiY)), new Point(Convert.ToInt32(posiX + 20), Convert.ToInt32(posiY2)) };

                g.DrawLine(p,Convert.ToInt32(posiX),Convert.ToInt32(min),Convert.ToInt32(posiX),Convert.ToInt32(max));
                g.FillPolygon(Brushes.Red, points);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, the triangle that is generated isn't fixed, it flashes and glitches. Is there any way I can stop the Paint event after it generates the triangles?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you need to code to execute only once why did you put it in the paint event of the chart? Why not adding it to the constructor?

Comment: Paint event is dangerous. It run many times, this is why you have this flickering. Try to put it on `Invalidated`

Comment: @wazaaaap Because I'm not doing it only once on the full program. This code is for demonstration purposes. I'm going to create a method to add points every x minutes. Also, if I put it in the constructor, I get a nullPointer

Comment: Never, *never* use CreateGraphics() to paint.  It "glitches" because you are splattering pixels directly to the screen.  They'll be very quickly overpainted again since the Chart control uses double-buffering.  Always use `e.Graphics`, pass it to your Paint() method.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant, but how do I color the inside of the triangle?

Comment: Already discovered, thanks for the tip @HansPassant

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To stop the flickering add `this.DoubleBuffered = true;` to the constructor of the form.
And to repaint the form every X minutes, add `Invalidate(true);` in the timer tick event (i assume you have timer).

Answer (score 0):

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.